Why is it less shocking to cross the bump with just one wheel?
Difference between 'go over speed bump with one side' and 'both sides at the same time'
I asked a similar question previously and received an excellent answer stating that when going over a speed bump with one side, the center of mass of the object only raises by half, resulting in less impact. Given that the vehicle's shape and mass are constant and the height of the speed bump is fixed(height = d) , the situation when crossing the speed bump with both wheels and with one wheel would look something like this:

Left involves the front edge, and right involves the side edge being at the same height d (the height of the speed bump) from the ground. According to the previous answer, in the situation on the left, the center of mass of the object is twice as high as in the situation on the right. Is my understanding correct?
Intuitively, it seems to me that the change in the height of the center of mass would be the same in both cases depicted in the above illustration. If the mass of the car is uniformly distributed, the center of mass would be located in the middle of that rectangle, and regardless of which edge is lifted, only half the weight of the vehicle would be required (torque equilibrium).

Therefore, the force needed to lift the car by the speed bump would be the same, and since the height of the speed bump doesn't change, why does the center of mass move only half the distance in one case? Please let me know what I might be missing.

@JánLalinský I don't understand that part. If the right rectangular prism in the first diagram shows one front wheel lifted, shouldn't the center of gravity also rise by d/2 when the front wheel is lifted by d?

This is not as simple as I thought. When one wheel is raised, I thought the car body would rotate about both axes, and the center of mass would be raised less than if two wheels were raised. But this does not seem to happen when I check with a box on table.

That's correct. When only one corner is lifted, it depends on how the edge that acts as an axis on the ground applies force. In some cases, only a single point touches the ground without any edge making contact.

If the height of the center of mass changes depending on how the object rotates, I'm curious whether the force required to lift a corner could also vary according to the principle of lever.

Static raise of center of mass depends on distribution of mass in the car. If the car is very flat, with center of mass near the wheels, then raise of one wheel will raise two more, with only one on the ground, and center of mass will raise less than if both front wheels were raised. This changes if center of mass gets higher. But all this seems a bad way to look at the problem, because the real bump is felt while the car is moving (so, not statics), and real cars have shock absorbers.

Good point. The missing piece is that there is a spring and shock absorber between each wheel and the car. If a wheel is moved to a higher position, the spring exerts a larger upward force on the car. The shock absorber resists changes in length and provides an upward force proportional to the upward velocity of the wheel.
If a wheel hits a bump, there is an immediate upward velocity in that wheel. That corner of the car accelerates upward. This lifts the two adjacent corners. The springs there lengthen, reducing the upward forces there.
If two wheels hit a bump, both exert upward forces. The upward force is twice as big, so the acceleration of the car is twice as big. Also, the rear wheels don't need to length, so their upward force doesn't change.

thx for answering again :) If the car moves upward at a constant speed without acceleration, will the height of the center of mass at the highest point be the same whether it passes over a bump with one wheel or both wheels? I think I might have missed considering the force exerted in the upward direction due to the collision with the bump when the car's speed (and the wheel's speed) is constant. Is that correct?

On level ground, the only time the car's upward speed is constant is when there is no bump. The height of the COM is an energy question. $E=mgh$. Since a car with springs is not a rigid object, it is hard to say how much energy it will gain from the bump. When the wheel is raised, some energy goes into kinetic and potential energy of the wheel, potential energy of the spring, heating the shock absorber, and potential energy of the body of the car. It depends on speed. If you drive very slowly, the whole car will lift. Fast, and just the wheel goes up.
